# Angle chasing in a circle

Tags: geometry

In the figure given below, $O$ is the centre of the circle. If two chords $PQ$ and $RS$ intersect at a point $A$, prove that $\angle POR+\angle QOS=2\angle PAR$

[image]

I could not even start. 
Please help me. I don't have any idea regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\widehat{POR}+\widehat{QOS} = 2\left(\widehat{PQR}+\widehat{SRQ}\right) = 2\left(\widehat{ARQ}+\widehat{AQR}\right)=2\widehat{PAR}.$$